# Geometrical Interpretation of function $\phi(n)$

Tags: geometry, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, graphing-functions, totient-function

We know that the $\phi(n)$ function denotes the total numbers which are co-prime to n , but like most of the mathematical concepts , can it be geometrically interpreted  ? Like in terms of graph?

If  yes , would it be like a normal graph of a function? Could we use more geometrical tools like finding it's slope , maximum and minimum etc. ??

**Edit : This question doesn't merely imply the possibility of the graph of the function , but to relate to the geometric interpretation and if possible , to use geometric means to find some characteristic properties of the function.**

Comment: It can't have a maximum:  $\phi(p)=p-1$ when $p$ is prime, and there are infinitely many primes.  Its minimum is $\phi(2)=1$.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/263243/lines-in-the-euler-phi-graph

Comment: @Anand the question is not only about understanding the trends in the graph , but also imposing a geometrical meaning to the function itself and it's slope.

Comment: The Nicolas criterion for the Riemann Hypothesis is $\frac{N_k}{\phi(N_k)}>e^\gamma \log\log N_k$ where the primorial $N_k$ is the product of the first k primes.

Answer (score 1):

$\phi$ is not a continuous function of a continuous variable. Interpolating its values to make a continuous function does not make much sense, nor is it very enlightening.

[image]

(image from [wikimedia](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:EulerPhi100.PNG))

Comment: can we relate it to a geometrical concept??

Comment: related to number of primitive pythagorean triples with $n$ as a leg already.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Graph of phi(n) form wikipedia]

This is how the graph looks like. Indeed this graph is discrete because $\phi(n)$ is an arithmetic function.